# Can I substitute this sentence with this?

Tags: grammar

situation 1

A: What is this photo about?
B: *This is the situation that he told me something.*

situation 2

A: What is this photo about?
B: *This is that he told me something.*

Can I substitute situation A with situation B?

If I can't, what is the difference between two sentences.

Comment: It's a little bit hard to give a definite answer, because neither sentence is grammatically correct.  I think what you want is something like "This is the situation that he told me about."

Comment: If stangdon is right about the first sentence, the second would be "This is what he told me about".

Comment: btw, it's a bit confusing using letters for both the situations and the speakers. Your question might be clearer if you used numbers for the situations and letters for the speakers,

Answer (score 1):

For either sentence, use *where* instead of *that*.

> A: What is this photo about?
>
> B: This is the situation *where* he told me something.
>
> A: What is this photo about?
>
> B: This is *where* he told me something.

You can substitute the second sentence for the first.

*Where* here is a relative pronoun.  The second clause is "restrictive" (e.g. define/adds essential information to the first clause) and therefore you want to use a word other than *that*, such as *which*, etc.

While *where* is normally is used for location, it can also be used to refer to a "time or occasion."  Read [this ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107249/where-as-a-conjunction) for details.